# My chance at the hole

Tags: riddle, story

> I live in a place that's dark and dry
>   Scrunched up with all of my friends, I wait.
>   I wait for the day my elder has died,
>   To get my chance at the hole.
>
> The hole is a hole, just thin enough for me
>   But my only prospect of seeing the world
>
> My friends around me are not really friends
>   Although they look like me, they're not for me
>   We're all competing to get to the hole.
>
> Only one of us can fit in the passageway out,
>   And once one of us enters it, it will be a long time before another can.
>   Some of us are taller, and some are shorter.
>   We all hate the tall ones.
>   There's a special reason why.
>
> Of course, getting through the hole is no easy task,
>   One's will often breaks in the process.
>   And then we are all happy, for this speeds up the line.
>
> The hole is a lottery, our only chance for life,
>   Yet once we catch a glimpse of the outside, we realize
>   The hole is just the entryway to another type of death.
>
> We are ripped from our bodies,
>   Dismembered and strewn all over
>   Until we are fatefully cleaned up
>   Erased from existence
>
> Making space for the next in line to the hole.

**Explain the story. Good Luck! :D**

Comment: such a well-written tragedy! +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> You are **a piece of lead**.

Explanation:

I live in a place that's dark and dry
Scrunched up with all of my friends, I wait.
I wait for the day my elder has died,
To get my chance at the hole.

> You live with other pieces of lead in a lead container, waiting for the currently used one to die so that you can get a chance to escape the hole in the container.

The hole is a hole, just thin enough for me
But my only prospect of seeing the world

> the hole in the container

My friends around me are not really friends
Although they look like me, they're not for me
We're all competing to get to the hole.

> You look like the other lead pieces, and you are all competing to escape.

Only one of us can fit in the passageway out,
And once one of us enters it, it will be a long time before another can.
Some of us are taller, and some are shorter.
We all hate the tall ones.
There's a special reason why.

> The container is designed to release one lead piece at a time, and you must wait for the current piece to be used up. The taller (longer) pieces are not only more desirable but also take longer to use.

Of course, getting through the hole is no easy task,
One's will often breaks in the process.
And then we are all happy, for this speeds up the line.

> Lead containers can take a few shakes to release a piece. Lead pieces are fragile, and broken pieces may get discarded.

The hole is a lottery, our only chance for life,
Yet once we catch a glimpse of the outside, we realize
The hole is just the entryway to another type of death.

> The lead piece that escapes is selected randomly. The chosen lead piece will be used until it dies.

We are ripped from our bodies,
Dismembered and strewn all over
Until we are fatefully cleaned up
Erased from existence

> Lead is scribbled all over paper, leaving its graphite remains. The written marks can also be removed with an eraser.

Making space for the next in line to the hole.

> Once one piece is used up, a new one is summoned.

Comment: Very easy, very fast :D Nice job. Did you like the story? :P

Comment: Yes, the story was beautifully tragic :)